Usage of 上に with た in this situation?
祖山はこの番組の主宰であるテレビ局から番組制作外注を受けている会社の人間だ。いわば下請け。
昔から外注とテレビ局のパワーバランスなど無いに等しく、パワハラだコンプラだと言ったところで意味はない。
局側からミスを指摘されて金額を落とされた上に、来季から発注を止めるから……などと言われれば会社の存続にかかわるのだ。
The sentence is pretty long. The narrator is explaining what his friend 祖山 does. He works as a sub contractor etc. However, because the balance between company and sub contractor is nonexistence, even if he complains about harassment, there's not point.
finally he adds
"局側からミスを指摘されて金額を落とされた上に、来季から発注を止めるから……などと言われれば会社の存続にかかわるのだ。
"
I understand
"来季から発注を止めるから……などと言われれば会社の存続にかかわるのだ。"
"He tells me things like "from next season we'll stop the program...putting  a danger on the company existence"
My reading from context is akin とき here? When x happens, he complains, but I'm not sure.

Here the expression 上に “and moreover” connects two assumed events that would “put a danger on the company existence”. That is, if 局側からミスを指摘されて金額を落とされる and moreover 来季から発注を止めるから……などといわれる, then 会社の存続にかかわる.
